# CLI run multiple commands and close terminal

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, scripting

I want to run the following commands and close the terminal:

```
mysqldump -udatabase -pdatabase database > db.sql && zip db.sql.zip db.sql && rm db.sql && mv db.sql.zip /var/www/vhosts/*/httpdocs && cd /var/www/vhosts/*/httpdocs && zip -r backup.zip . && cd && touch backup_is_ready
```

It works fine when the terminal is open, but the ZIP will be about 40GB and I want to be able to close the terminal, or else a disconnect can terminate the process.

So I have commands A && B

I tried:

```
(A &) && (B &)

(A && B) &

{A && B} &

nohup sh -c "A && B"

nohup { A && B } &
```

and many other options, but nothing worked.

I just want to put the command string in the terminal, then close the terminal, come back after 1 hour and get it ready.

I also have a longer command chain that starts with

```
sh <(wget -O - https://autoinstall.plesk.com/one-click-installer) && plesk bin init_conf --init -name "John Doe" -passwd "mypassword" -email "admin@example.com" -send_announce false -trial_license true -license_agreed true && plesk bin subscription --create example.com -owner admin -service-plan "Unlimited" -ip 000.000.000.000 -login username -passwd 'password' && ...
```

My command chains work great when the terminal is open, I only want to close it after putting the command chain in the terminal, but I don't want to create a file for it.

Is there any syntax that works without need to create a bash file?

Comment: are you planning to `ssh` to this host? If so, you can redirect multiple commands to the ssh session. If this is relevant to you, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Yes, I am using MobaXterm

Comment: Rather than me butchering an explanation, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4412338/3465014, I've also added this info to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ctrl + Z to stop (pause) the program and get back to the shell.
2. `bg` to run it in the background.
3. `disown -h [job-spec]` where *[job-spec]* is the job number (like %1 for the first running job; find about your number with the jobs command) so that the job isn't killed when the terminal closes.

Answer (score 0):

To startup a program in the background, use:

```
<your command> &
```

What I'd recommend is simply running what you'd like as two separate commands. Try:

```
user@hostname$ A &
user@hostname$ B &
```

If this process is too arduous or needs to be run frequently, you can enter these commands into a [shell script](https://www.shellscript.sh/). This script can then be run with

```
/path/to/my_script.sh &
```

**Update:**

Based on additional info in your comments, for an overview of how to ssh to a host, run multiple commands, and then disconnect, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4412338/3465014

Comment: Unfortunally it only affects the currently running command, so when A runs, B doesn't start when terminal is closed.

<command1 && command2> & returns syntax error

Comment: @GoodGuy, you shouldn't close the terminal until you have run both `A &` and `B &` manually. I've updated my answer to have some additional info about shell scripts.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually the goal is to close the terminal after execute the commands. Can I also cretae a script and run it, like --- touch script && printf \"A && B && C\" > script && sh script --- ?

Comment: You can close the terminal by using the `exit` command at the end of the script. You should be able to run the script fine like that. Make sure that at the end you do something like `sh ./script` or `sh /full/path/to/script`. You need to put the path to the script in your final command. Simply doing 'sh script' won't work.

Comment: A major benefit of scripting however is that it doesn't need to be re-created each time so the long one-liner may not be necessary after it has been created.